# How do I calculate the average duration of a cell range if the duration is under 10 minutes in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate the average of a list of durations. However, I want to calculate the  average duration if the duration is under 10 minutes. I tried using `=AVERAGEIF(D2:D207,<MINUTE(10)))` and `=AVERAGEIF(D2:D207,<VALUE("00:10:00"))`, but I get a formula parse or divide by 0 error. Is there a formula solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

In Sheets, 10 minutes is represented as 1/144.

```
=AVERAGEIF(D2:D207,"<"&1/144)
```